# How to show spaces in CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

So I wanted my cmd to select random sentences.

```
set /a rnd=%random%%%5
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (list.txt) do if %rnd%==%%a  echo %%b
```

Im using this but inside the list.txt file I have sentences with spaces.
For some reason cmd only shows the first word and it doesnt with the rest.

For example a sentence in the file.

> Hello how are you?

This would show as

> Hello
>   and that's all.

But if I type it like this

> Hello_how_are_you?

then it does show all the words but it does include all the `_`'s

Any idea how to make the spaces show without replacing them with signs?

Comment: If you use `"tokens=1*"` then `a` will hold the first field, and `b` will hold the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct the `for` loop to grab all remaining tokens using the wildcard token '*' like this:

```
set /a rnd=%random% %% 5 
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (list.txt) do if %rnd%==%%a echo %%b
```

Here, the first token is assigned to `%%a` and all of the remaining tokens to `%%b`. Note that any whitespace between tokens is replaced by exactly one blank.